# How to store array of objects in a variable in kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

I want to call a post API whose parameters is an array of objects
eg:

```
{
"articles":[
    {
    "mobile":85634293205468,
    "name":"Name1"
    },
    {
    "mobile":9535934854445,
    "name":"Name2"
    },
    {
        "mobile":589524452264,
        "name":"Name3"
    }
    ],
"user_id":143324757
}
```

is there a way to make a variable of array of objects type so that I can call for this API.
I am a beginner in android please tell me the reason if the question is not clear.

Thank you

Comment: You need a serialization library to convert JSON into classes. Such as GSON or the kotlinx.serialization library. You can look up instructions for using them on their official sites.

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy [JSON to Kotlin](https://json2kt.com) converter, which converts json to this classes:

```
data class UserModel (

  @SerializedName("articles" ) var articles : ArrayList<Articles> = arrayListOf(),
  @SerializedName("user_id"  ) var userId   : Int?                = null

)

data class Articles (

  @SerializedName("mobile" ) var mobile : Int?    = null,
  @SerializedName("name"   ) var name   : String? = null

)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how could I use it with volley library.

Comment: I don't know how you are making requests, but there is gson library, which can be used to convert classes to json string, and vice versa. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md